# how to know which versions of hibernate/spring data are used in spring-boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data, version

i work with a spring-boot project,

```
 <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

How can i check.. :

- which version of hibernate is linked to my project ?
- which version of spring-data is linked to my project ?

could you explain me the good workflow in my Eclipse IDE to check this ?

Answer (score 7):

You have two options:

- Using your IDE under Dependencies Section
- Using terminal - `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 1):

In your eclipse IDE when you open pom.xml, few tab like structures will come below like shown in below picture.

[image: pic1]

In this you can go to dependency hierarchy section which will show you both dependency hierarchy and resolved dependency. In resolved dependencies you can search for whichever jar you want like hibernate/spring-data and see which version is getting used. Below is a picture for your reference which shows commons-httpclient jar with version 2.0.2 getting used.

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipes IDE double click on your project . click on show in > terminal
then write comand -> mvn dependency:tree hit enter you will see all the dependency of that project