# How to know exactly if my spring boot application is using hibernate or not?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lombok

this might be a dumb question, i have a spring boot application generated using Lombok, so i want to know if its using hibernate as a default orm ot not ?

is there a way to know such thing ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870905/how-to-know-which-versions-of-hibernate-spring-data-are-used-in-spring-boot-proj. Just run `mvn dependency:tree`
 to show all dependencies of your project, perform search for hibernate dependency

Comment: well i did look there but i got so confused i did find spring-boot-data-jpa-start and hibernate core i guess that means he's using hibernate right ?

Comment: yes, hibernate dependency should be under `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. It means that you are using it. Also you can see log about `org.hibernate.Version` during startup server it also means that yor server is using hibernate